# Python: Maximum Recursion depth exceeded Error | Working with Quandl API to fetch stock price data

Tags: python, recursion, quandl

I am trying to fetch stock market data from Quandl for a list of ticker symbols scraped from S&P 500.

The API call is wrapped in a function and a for loop that iterates over a list of ticker symbols and passes them to the API call statement. However, upon running the function I am running into Recursion error.

Here's my code block. The function takes two argument, API call and a list of tickr symbols.

The API call is made by qd.get_table statement:

```
def get_quandl_data(quandl_code, tickr):
    tickr_list = []
    for i in tickr:
        tickr_list.append(i)
        #print(tickr_list[0])
        #API call to fetch data
        df = qd.get_table(quandl_code, qopts = {'columns': ['ticker', 'date', 'close']}, ticker=tickr_list, date = { 'gte': '2014-01-01', 'lte': '2017-11-01' }, paginate=True)
        tickr_list.remove(i)
        #Save data as pickle
        df.to_pickle('qd_data.pickle')
return df
```

The error thrown is: 
"RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" and it points to the API call line in the code.

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-950ac093b844> in <module>()
----> 1 qd_data = get_quandl_data('WIKI/PRICES', tickrs)
      2 qd_data.head()

<ipython-input-48-d23d88ffb155> in get_quandl_data(quandl_code, tickr)
      5         #print(tickr_list[0])
      6         #API call to fetch data
----> 7         df = qd.get_table(quandl_code, qopts = {'columns': ['ticker', 'date', 'close']}, ticker=tickr_list, date = { 'gte': '2014-01-01', 'lte': '2017-11-01' }, paginate=True)
      8         tickr_list.remove(i)
      9         #Save data as pickle
```

The desired behavior of the code is to create a data frame with stock market data fetched by the API for all ticker symbols in the list.

Comment: Have you tried using a smaller date range for your query?

Comment: Yes. I tried using last 10 months - still seeing the error.